# Outputing string values from objects saved in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a small problem with printing out strings that are stored in an object. The object is stored in an ArrayList.

I have three clases that I use im my program:

Friend Class:

```
package one;

public class Friend implements InterfaceFriend {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public Friend(String name, String phone, String email) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPhone(String phone1) {
        phone1 = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEmail(String email1) {
        email1 = email;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name1) {
        name1 = name;
    }

}
```

FriendInterface:

```
package one;

public interface InterfaceFriend {
    String getPhone(); // Returns phone number.

    String getEmail(); // Returns email.

    String getName(); // Returns name.

    void setPhone(String phone); // Sets phone.

    void setEmail(String email); // Sets email.

    void setName(String name); // Sets name.
}
```

and Test Class:

```
package one;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FriendTest {

    static List<Friend> friends;
    static Friend friend;


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();

        friend = new Friend("Jane Doe", "085-5555555", "jane.doe@gmail.com");
        friends.add(friend);

        friend = new Friend("John Doe", "085-1111111", "john.doe@gmail.com");
        friends.add(friend);

        friend = new Friend("Paul Weller", "085-3333333", "paul.weller@gmail.com");
        friends.add(friend);

        System.out.println("Friends added to list:");

        System.out.println(friends.toString());

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I am running the `System.out.println(friends.toString());`from the Test Class i am getting this:
**Friends added to list:
[one.Friend@38f0b51d, one.Friend@4302a01f, one.Friend@615e7597]**

Instead the Strings with the values that I want. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Override the `toString()` method in your `Friend` class.

Comment: In addition to `toString()` you also need to make sure your `Friend(String,String,String)` constructor is implemented - because that seems to be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you friend class you need to override `toString()`

```
public class Friend implements InterfaceFriend {
    ...
    ...

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + email + " " + phone; // or whatever format you want printed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to override the `toString()` method in the `Friend` class as commented already, but you also need to complete the constructor that you're using.

```
public Friend(String name, String phone, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Moreover, the code in your setters are backwards.

Answer (score 0):

you simply override toString method.  place this inside of Friend class. problem solved..

```
public String toString(){
   // return  your Strings..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override to toString() in your class, to what output suits you. The reason you're getting that output is because the default toString() provided in objects is a hash code.

```
public String toString(){
   return name; //assuming you only want to display the name else edit it

}
```